# PDO::rowCount() retornando -1

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Tenho essa rotina abaixo, qual utilizava sem problemas com um banco MySQL. Porém precisei migrar para um banco SQL Server 2008, o que foi simples.

O único problema é que, não sei por qual motivo o meu `rowCount()` esta retornando `-1`, mesmo com minha query funcionando sem problema, pois se eu der um `print_r` no retorno do SQL, todas as linhas que deveriam vir na consulta estão lá.

Segue meu código:

```
public function listar(){

    $retorno = array();

    $sql = "SELECT m.id, m.descricao, m.link, m.categoria, m.icone FROM menus AS m,    grupos AS g, permissoes AS p WHERE (g.id = p.idgrupo AND m.id = p.idmenu) AND (p.status = :pstatus AND g.status = :gstatus AND m.status = :mstatus) AND g.id = :gid ORDER BY m.ordem ;";

    $vars = array(":pstatus"=>1,":gstatus"=>1,":mstatus"=>1,":gid"=>$_SESSION['group']);

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    foreach($vars as $index => $value){
        $stmt->bindValue($index,$value);
    }

    if($stmt->execute()){
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $rows['msg'] = '1';
        $rows['length'] = $count;

        $i = 0;
        while($i < $count){
            foreach($rows[$i] as $index => $value){
                $rows[$i]->$index = utf8_encode($value);
            }
            $i++;
        }

        return $rows;
    } else {
        return array("msg" => '0');
    }

}
```

Comment: Comentário relacionado no manual do PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#113608

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com base no link que o @bfavaretto me enviou, eu consegui chegar numa solução, segue.

Na linha em que o `prepare()` é definido, deve se acrescentar o seguinte parâmetro `array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)`. Então a linha do prepare fica assim.

`$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql,array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));`

Depois disso o `rowCount()` funcionará sem problemas.

Obrigado pelas respostas.

Answer (score 3):

Esse é o problema quando um select é enviado não é garantido que todos os banco retornem o número de linhas(ele retorna o número de linhas afetadas por uma DML: DELETE, INSERT, ou UPDATE), o proprio [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) alerta sobre ele.

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
> a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
> returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
> for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
> applications.
>
> Se a última instrução SQL executado pelo PDOStatement associada foi
> Uma instrução SELECT, alguns bancos de dados pode retornar o número de linhas
> Retornado por essa afirmação. No entanto, esse comportamento não é garantida
> Para todos os bancos de dados e não deve ser invocado para portáteis
> Aplicações.

Para contonar essa situação faça um select com count(). Outra solução seria usar o [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) do php **desde que a consulta não tenha resultados agregados**. `count()` retorna o número de linhas do array.

Comment: vlw pela resposta, eu pensei nessas soluções que você sugeriu, porém eu queria evitar uma segunda query apenas com a função de contador, então eu estava procurando uma outra solução.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro na próximas questões você pode citar que já tentou X ou Y, isso ajuda a direcionar uma resposta diferente.