# Contando linhas atingidas PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou fazendo uma query e preciso contar o número de linhas retornadas, não estou usualmente acostumado em fazer isto em PDO, segue o meu código abaixo.

```
$sqlCODCEL = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_CELULAS WHERE TXT_CODIG_SECUR = :codCEL");
$sqlCODCEL->bindParam(":codCEL", $lbl_CODCELULA);
$linha = $sqlCODCEL->fetchAll();
$count = count_chars($linha);

error_log($count);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que você consiga retornar a quantidade de linhas afetadas, você tem que usar `rowCount();`.

Provavelmente, `$linhasafetadas = $sqlCODCEL->rowCount()` irá resolver seu problema.

---

Um exemplo:

```
<?php
/* Delete all rows from the FRUIT table */
$del = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM fruit');
$del->execute();

/* Return number of rows that were deleted */
print("Return number of rows that were deleted:\n");
$count = $del->rowCount();
print("Deleted $count rows.\n");
?>
```

Retorno:

> Return number of rows that were deleted:
>   Deleted 9 rows.

Fonte: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 6):

Use o método [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) ele retorna as linhas afetadas por uma DML(insert, update delete) em alguns bancos de dados também retorna as linhas de um select, no mysql funciona corretamente.

```
$linhas =$sqlCODCEL->rowCount();
```

Relacionado:

[Como obter o número de linhas de um select com SQL Server.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43275/91)