# Contar sem usar rowCount do PDO

Tags: php, mvc

sou novo com **PHP PDO**, estou usando **MVC** e não consegui fazer a contagem de linhas no *banco de dados* usando `$obj->rowCount();`

Segue o meu código

**model.php**:

```
public function read($table, $fields, $where = null, $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {

    $where = isset($where) ? "WHERE {$where}" : "";

    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table} {$where} ");

    return $sql->fetchAll($fetchMode);

}
```

**login_model.php**

```
public function login() {
    $id = 1;
    $sql = $this->read('users', 'email', "id={$id}");
    print_r($sql);
    if (count($sql) >= 1) {
        echo 'é maior';
    } else {
        echo 'é menor';
    }
}
```

como viram estou usando `count()` para fazer a contagem, pois eu não consegui fazer usando `rowCount();` por falta de lógica :/

Comment: [Contando linhas atingidas PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82168/91)

Comment: Olha a função, por exemplo `$sql = $obj->read(aqui a query)` não consigo fazer isso `$sql->rowCount()` '-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu método retorna apenas `$sql` e não os resultados (`fetchAll()`.

```
public function read($table, $fields, $where = null, $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $where = isset($where) ? "WHERE {$where}" : "";
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table} {$where} ");
    return $sql;
}
```

Na chamda faça:

```
$sql = $this->read('users', 'email', "id={$id}");
echo $sql->rowCount();
```

Comment: Não consigo usar assim `$sql = $this->read('users', 'email', "id={$id}");
echo $sql->rowCount();` não sei por que.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves aparece algum erro?

Comment: sim, retorna isso `Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in`

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves sua consulta entao falhou.

Comment: Deu certo escrevi $sqls ao invez de $sql, apenas return $sql deu certo obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php

**EDIT (Tradução):**

Se a ultima query de SQL executada através do PDOStatement foi uma query do tipo select alguns bancos de dados podem retornar o numero de rows selecionadas, no entanto, outros bancos de dados poderão não retornar e por isso o comportamento não é garantido para todos os bancos de dados e por isso não deve ser invocado em aplicações portateis.

Poderá não estar perfeito, mas encontro-me no trabalho de momento e isto é o melhor que consigo fazer para lhe ajudar.

Comment: Poderia traduzir para pt?

Comment: Vou apenas traduzir a parte importante. Aguarde o edit no post principal

Comment: Está editado e em português. boa sorte.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando MySQL pode contornar a situação com o uso do sql_calc_found_rows e found_rows().

Segue um link de um artigo que faz uso desses recursos.

http://www.marcosborges.com/blog/2010/08/13/select-sql_calc_found_rows-no-mysql/

O mais interessante é que ele retorna o total de linhas encontradas mesmo utilizando as clásulas LIMIT e OFFSET. Eu utilizo muito esse recurso para fazer paginação nos sistemas que faço.