# PDO - Qual é melhor: columnCount ou rowCount?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Sou novo em PDO (fui obrigado a escolher entre mysqli e pdo apos migrar o php da versão 5.2 para a 7.0) e fiz um sistema onde o usuário faz a busca:

```
$b2 = $_POST['b2'];
$busca = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE titulo LIKE '%$b2%' UNION SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE corpo LIKE '%$b2%'");

$total->columnCount();
```

OU

```
$total->rowCount();
```

No fim vai ser usada para exibir a seguinte informação:

```
A busca retornou <?php echo $total ?> resultados;
```

Comment: [columnCount()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.columncount.php) retorna a quantidade de colunas, e [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php) retorna a quantidade de registros ( Linhas ).

Answer (score 1):

Não é questão de "qual é a melhor", são funções com finalidades diferentes.

Segundo a documentação do PDO:

> columnCount — Retorna o número de colunas obtidas no resultado da consulta

e

> rowCount - Retorna o número de linhas afetadas pela declaração do SQL

[rowCount só vai retornar algo se você fizer DELETE, INSERT ou UPDATE. Algumas bases de dados podem retornar o número de registro se você só fizer um SELECT, mas não é garantido.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Como `fetchAll` retorna um array, você pode simplesmente utilizar `count` para verificar o número de resultados

```
count($busca->fetchAll())
```

Comment: Quando eu disse "qual é a melhor" eu quis dizer qual é a mais recomendada/performatica/rapida pra essa situação, mas vou testar com fetchAll também, agradeço pela resposta.

Comment: se você quiser contar as linhas, `columnCount` não é uma opção, logo, só te resta `rowCount` ou fazer um `count` no array de resultados.

Comment: Engraçado @juniorgarcia aqui ambos (columnCount, rowCount e count($busca->fetchAll()) retornaram o mesmo resultado e funcionaram, por enquanto estou escolhendo columnCount, li na documentação do php.net que fetchAll busca TODOS os resultados da linha, então imagino ser a mais pesada pra buscar e mostrar a paginação, me corrija se eu estiver errado...

Comment: `fetchAll` vai retornar todas as linhas que se enquadram no seu `SELECT`. Já que você quer paginação, pode usar apenas `fetch` e rodar dentro de um loop para controlá-lo. Assim, não precisa pegar todas as linhas. E `columnCount` é para contar colunas, não resultados. Lembre disso :)

Answer (score 0):

[`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) e [`columnCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php) têm finalidades.

`rowCount()` retorna o número de linhas afetadas por um INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE que é o equivalente a [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Como o PDO oferece suporte a vários bancos de dados em alguns como MySQL esse método também retorna o número de linhas de um SELECT assim como  [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php). Em outros bancos de dados são necessárias algumas configurações.

`columnCount()` Retorna um número de colunas de um SELECT

**Relacionda:**

[SQL SERVER - PDO::rowCount() retornando -1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43271/91)